# Spring TCP send data over incoming connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How can I configure Spring to receive a TCP connection and then send data over it? I have data stored in a RabbitMQ queue, and I need to send this data over an incoming connection.

I assume client is working as `client-mode=true` according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-adapters). I have found an example on how to behave as a client in this use-case, but I can't find an example for the server side. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I am not sure if this is a standard use-case, it seems backwards to me that the client is starting the connection and not the server, but I have little experience with TCP.

Comment: But the same documentation has inbound configuration example 2 paragraphs lower ;]

Comment: I guess I don't understand how it is supposed to work... The `TcpInboundGateway` has a `request-channel` and a `reply-channel` to return a reply to a request. If a client connects without any message, just wants to receive data, I am still supposed to use the `TcpInboundGateway`?

Comment: Yes at the client is still "initializind" side. Remember that sending data is long after connection establishment. If you have connection esablished, then you are allowed to write data to underlying sockets, no matter what client is doing.

Comment: Use an outbound adapter with a server connection factory. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need client mode; that's for when you want an inbound adapter to initiate the socket open. Use a `TcpSendingMessageHandler` with a server connection factory, to listen on the port.

Add an `ApplicationListener` bean that listens for a `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` [see TCP Connection Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events).

The event will have the connection id, which you must capture and set in a message header (`IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID`) for any messages sent, so the adapter knows where to send the message.

Comment: I assume you meant `TcpSendingMessageHandler`? If I want to send the message to all open connections, I assume I would have to multiply the message per connection id that came from the server connection factory (`connectionFactoryName` parameter of the event) and remove the connections on `TcpConnectionClosedEvent`?

Comment: Yes, sorry; fixed. If you want to broadcast to all connections, you can just call `getOpenConnectionIds()` on the server connection factory; it will return a list of the currently open connection ids (there's a race so you need to catch exceptions in case a connection closed in the meantime).